# Ошибка при загрузке Linux

Tags: linux, systemd

При загрузке Xubuntu 18.04 стала проскакивать красная строчка (FAILED). Это происходит так быстро, что мне пришлось фотографировать экран, в логах я её не нашёл. Никаких проблем в пользовании системой у меня нет, но ошибку хотелось бы исправить.

В ней сказано, что я должен запустить `systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` чтобы узнать детали ошибки и собственно вот они:

```
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-11-24 05:04:49 EET; 2min 24s ago
     Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
           man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
  Process: 526 ExecStart=/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove --boot --exclude-prefix=/dev (code=exited, status=1/FAI
 Main PID: 526 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd-tmpfiles[526]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/colord/icc, refusing.
Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd-tmpfiles[526]: Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/systemd/coredump, refusing.
Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 05:04:49 MAINFRAME systemd[1]: Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
```

Мне эти логи мало о чём говорят. Вероятно, нужно заменить симлинки на реальные пути? Но ведь не я эти симлинки создавал. Мало ли, для чего они нужны.

UPD: Только что прошёлся по этим путям - `/var/lib/colord/icc`, `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` и оказалось что это обычные пустые папки, никакие не симлинки. Так что вообще ума не приложу, чего ему надо от меня.

UPD: Погуглил эту ошибку, [вот что нашёл](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094776/systemd-tmpfiles-wont-start) - вроде как кому-то удалось решить такую же проблему командой `chown root.root /`, но мне не помогло.

Comment: а в путях есть симлинки? `man tmpfiles.d` и `man systemd-tmpfiles` к прочтению... если ручками запустить `/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove --boot --exclude-prefix=/dev` то также падает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer симлинков в путях нет и при запуске вручную выдаёт всё те же ошибки: `Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/colord/icc, refusing`, `Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/lib/systemd/coredump, refusing`.

Comment: а права (пользователь/группа) на все директории от корня до означенных корректные?

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за помощь. Разобрался :)

Comment: подсказка: для получения информации о всех каталогах в цепочке удобно использовать программу *namei*. например, просмотр принадлежности: `$ namei -o /путь/куда/нибудь`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решена. Причина была в том, что mysql каким-то образом втихаря объявил себя владельцем папки `/var/lib`. Я вернул права руту и ошибки больше нет.